# Especificar tipo de un parámetro de clase como la misma clase que extiende de una interfaz

Tags: typescript

Estoy haciendo un bot de discord en nestjs con nestjs-plus/discovery para obtener los provider con el decorador Command. por lo que cuando escribo un comando cuando se llama el metodo handler del comando, accedo a handler,meta y no al la clase donde estoy, le añadí instance, entonces en handler lo tengo que convertir.
¿Como pudo hacer que no tenga que hacer la conversión cada vez que quiera usar instance?

##### command.module.ts

```
this.providersCommands = await this.discover.providerMethodsWithMetaAtKey<CommandOpt>("command")
...
this.providersCommands.map(command....
...
 return  {
     handler: command.discoveredMethod.handler,
     meta: command.meta,
     instance: command.discoveredMethod.parentClass.instance
 }
...
 phraseCommand.command.handler({
    message,
    text,
    regexp: {
      end: phraseCommand.end,
      phrase: phraseCommand.phrase
    },
    client: this.discord.getClient(),
    instance: phraseCommand.command.instance
  })
```

##### answers.command.ts

```
export class AnswersCommand implements CommandHandler {
    constructor(private readonly answersService: AnswersService) { }
    @Command({
        phrases: ["responde"],
    })
    handler({ message,instance }: CommandArgs): void {
        message.channel.send( (instance as AnswersCommand).answersService.findAll());
    }
}
```

##### command.ts

```
import Discord from 'discord.js';
export interface CommandHandler {
    handler({message,text,regexp,client}:CommandArgs): void
}
export interface CommandArgs {
    message:Discord.Message,
    text: string,
    regexp: {
        end:number
        phrase:string
    },
    client:Discord.Client,
    instance:any
}
```